# What is the name of a written legacy of personal wisdom?

Tags: phrase-requests, books

I am collecting the wisdom of elders, publishing in books their insights and stories, focused on the theme "What does your life stand for?"
I wonder if there is a name for such books. Or if we can invent one?
Thanks for your help.

Comment: Meditations? Quotes? Epigrams?

Answer (score -1):

> I wonder if there is a name for such books?

As it is your book, with poetic license you can choose any title you like.  Two suggestions:

**Thought(s)**  [TFD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/thought)

> 2. A product [**your book**] of thinking or other mental activity: What are your thoughts on this matter?

*musing*

usually **Musings**  [Oxford](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/musing)

> A period of reflection or thought.

As in:

*Thoughts of X Elders* or *Musings of X Elders*.

Comment: "Musings" is typically self-deprecatory as there is a strong sense of "whim" mixed into the meaning. It probably won't fit with OP's attempt to create some reverent corpus of wisdom.

Comment: As in "Oh, I'm just a batty old geezer, you don't need to listen to my senile musings, but <insert incredibly profound thing here>".

Comment: The question doesn't ask for a *title*, it asks "if there is a name for such books". I interpret that to mean *a descriptive term for that category or genre*, like "memoir" is to personal recollections, "novel" is to prose fiction, "religious text" is to, um, religious texts...